# Powershell connecting from a linux client to a windows remote

Tags: linux, powershell, windows-10, remote-access

I am trying to remotely connect to a windows machine from my Linux workstation.

I installed powershell on my Arch Linux workstation and I am currently trying to connect to the host.

On the host:

`Enable-PSRemoting`

Then allowed all hosts with
`Set-Item wsman:\localhost\client\trustedhosts *`

Checking everything with:

```
PS C:\windows\system32> ls WSMan:\localhost\shell


   WSManConfig: Microsoft.WSMan.Management\WSMan::localhost\Shell

Type            Name                           SourceOfValue   Value
----            ----                           -------------   -----
System.String   AllowRemoteShellAccess                         true
System.String   IdleTimeout                                    7200000
System.String   MaxConcurrentUsers                             2147483647
System.String   MaxShellRunTime                                2147483647
System.String   MaxProcessesPerShell                           2147483647
System.String   MaxMemoryPerShellMB                            2147483647
System.String   MaxShellsPerUser                               2147483647
```

Now when I try to connect from Linux workstation:

```
PS /home/user/tmp> Enter-PSSession -ComputerName "myuser" -Credential DOMAIN\myuser

Windows PowerShell credential request
Enter your credentials.
Password for user DOMAIN\myuser: *****************

Enter-PSSession : MI_RESULT_ACCESS_DENIED
At line:1 char:1
+ Enter-PSSession -ComputerName "myuser" -Credential DOMAIN\ajpalhare ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (myuser:String) [Enter-PSSession
   ], PSInvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CreateRemoteRunspaceFailed
```

I don't anything on the the winrm windows event logs.

Any suggestions welcome,

Answer (score 5):

WinRM from Linux/OSX is not currently supported but support is on the way.

https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/942

Answer (score 1):

Have you also enabled Remoting over HTTP/HTTPS?

At the most basic, this involves these commands:

```
winrm set winrm/config/client/auth @{Basic="true"}
winrm set winrm/config/service/auth @{Basic="true"}
winrm set winrm/config/service @{AllowUnencrypted="true"}
```

Probably better to use HTTPS and a self signed cert.
This is a nice guide:
http://www.joseph-streeter.com/?p=1086

Or just use the script provided by ansible:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ansible/ansible/devel/examples/scripts/ConfigureRemotingForAnsible.ps1

have fun

Comment: "*Basic authentication has acceptable security over https, but all communications using basic authentication over http are unencrypted. [..] Note that this sends passwords over unencrypted http. We do not recommend it.*" - https://github.com/PowerShell/psl-omi-provider

Comment: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/977381ef-dc7a-4e4a-8457-323ed4c32639/can-you-execute-winrm-2-set-commands-wthin-powershell-2#891e986c-2620-4756-a6eb-743f1ad1f337

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to do with PowerShell Core (server and client) and OpenSSH.

```
Enter-PSSession -HostName myserver -UserName myuser
```

Read the articles:

- [Using the OpenSSH Beta in Windows 10 Fall Creators Update and Windows Server 1709](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2017/12/15/using-the-openssh-beta-in-windows-10-fall-creators-update-and-windows-server-1709/)
- [PowerShell Remoting Over SSH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/core-powershell/ssh-remoting-in-powershell-core?view=powershell-6)